# Why use $ for print message in kotlin

Tags: kotlin

I created basic app which will demonstrate about `kotlin` programming.
here i used method which will print array size, i used 2 scenario for print.

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)      
            main()  
        }
           private fun main(){
          val letter : Char
          val arrayNumber: IntArray = intArrayOf(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9)        
          println("with : " +"${arrayNumber.size}")
          println("without : " +arrayNumber.size)        
      }
}
```

here is output :

```
 I/System.out: with : 9
 I/System.out: without : 9
```

I searched a lot but not getting positive, if anybody know it will be more helpful.

Comment: because you can get rid of the + sign. Use `println("with : ${arrayNumber.size}")` and not what you put. Reduces the noise by eliminating string concatenation.

Comment: @Mikezx6r thanks for simple solution.

Comment: @yole thanks for suggestion.

Answer (score 3):

The first form with `$` is a string template, that is a piece of code that is evaluated and whose result is concatenated into the string.

The two forms are basically equivalent, but using string templates usually leads to more compact code with less syntactic noise.

See: [String Templates](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/basic-types.html#string-templates) in the Kotlin language reference